# How to change aggregation on Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to find the option to report sum of sales by month and country in data in Power BI.

[image]

At the moment the package defaults to count of sales and it reports like this:

I want change it so the chart reports and splits out the country.

Answer (score 0):

On the Visualizations pane select the dropdown arrow on the Sales parameter and then switch from Count to Sum:

[image]

Comment: I can't see those options.

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner. My tool of choices is Pandas. I guess I won't get this job, but i appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I'm sure it is relatively easy to check dtypes in Power BI?

Comment: Yep. Plain vanilla.

Comment: Elksie, maybe an introductory Power BI tutorial would be a great addition to your playlist.